# MySQL DB import/export command line in Windows

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, import, export

How do I import and export a local instance of a MySQL database via command-line interface?

My operating system is Windows and [WampServer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs) server is installed.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105776/how-do-i-restore-a-mysql-dump-file/105798

Answer (score 51):

Use this for export:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > filename.sql
```

this is my Sample Export in CMD and i'll save in drive D:\

```
mysqldump -u root -pmypassword pos > d:\pos.sql
```

Comment: This is the first time am doing the export using sql, 
Tell my my sql can place any where , that is my file may in desktop or d drive , or is there any particular location i have past my sql file

Comment: you can place your file anywhere as long as you have your mysql bin folder in your PATH. the alternative is to call the mysql and mysqldump executables using the full path to them (e.g F:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin\mysql and F:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin\mysqldump) . In your screenshot the problem is that you didn't supply the username and password when starting the mysql program (you supply it with: mysql -u USERNAME -p <enter> and then type your password)

Answer (score 24):

To backup:

```
mysqldump -u user -p database > backup.sql
```

To import:

```
mysql -u user -p database < backup.sql
```

Comment: mysql> mysqldump -u root -p sale > backup.sql
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
dump -u root -p sale > backup.sql' at line 1

Comment: @Bharanikumar I don't think you didn't find out, but you need to use the mysqldump.exe not the mysql.exe.

Answer (score 10):

Follow the following steps.

1. Run cmd command
2. Type c: or d: on command prompt. This will be based on your WAMP server installations.
3. Assuming you have installed wamp on C: drive.
4. `C:\>cd wamp`
5. `C:\wamp>cd bin`
6. `C:\wamp\bin>cd mysql`
7. `C:\wamp\bin\mysql>cd mysql15.5.8`
8. `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.5.8>cd bin`
9. `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.5.8\bin>mysql.exe -u root`

Now you'll get mysql command prompt.

** Note Here My MySql version ins 15.5.8 it may change based on your wamp installation.
Now you can follow the answer by @Matei. I'm pasting his answer here. Hope this will help you.

to export:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > filename.sql
```

and to Import:

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < filename.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to folder `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\MYSQL_VERSION\bin`

Hit shift + right-click in that folder and select "Open command window here" from the menu that pops up.

This will open a command window in the path you are already in, so `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\MYSQL_VERSION\bin`

Enter any of the MySQL commands you like with any of the executables you find in that folder.

**To export:**

```
mysqldump -u db_user -pDB_PASSWORD db_name > /path/to/save/backup_file.sql
```

**To import:**

```
mysql -u db_user -p db_name < /path/to/save/backup_file.sql
```

The user has a password (DB_PASSWORD) and that needs to be directly behind -p without a space. Beware like this the password can be seen by other programs.

If you do **not** specify a password in the command directly after the -p flag and just use the db_name you will be asked to put in the password interactively every time you run the command.

This means every time you want to export or import your databse you have to put in the password. This is also not very secure and like this you cannot run a script to automatically export your database at a given time interval.

So it is best to follow this advice:

Quoting the MySQL documentation:
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html):

> Store your password in an option file. For example, on Unix you can list your password in the [client] section of the .my.cnf file in your home directory:
>
> ```
> [client]
> password=your_pass
> ```
>
> To keep the password safe, the file should not be accessible to anyone but yourself. To ensure this, set the file access mode to 400 or 600. For example:
>
> ```
> shell> chmod 600 .my.cnf
> ```
>
> To name from the command line a specific option file containing the password, use the `--defaults-file=file_name` option, where `file_name` is the full path name to the file.

Answer (score 1):

To export data in MySQL through msdos is

Traverse `bin` folder of your `mysql` directory and search for `mysqldump` or put it in environmental variables to access it from anywhere

1. If user is root with no password

`mysqldump -uroot -p mydb > backup.sql`

2. If username and password

`mysqldump -u <username> -p <password> <databasename> > backup.sql`

(provide the username and password and dbname)

Comment: I am using MySQL on Windows, but `c:\>where *mysqldump*` say that it not exists.

Answer (score 0):

mysql -u user -p database < backup.sql

Answer (score 0):

Install HeidiSQl it Easy way to Export Mysql File. Also it is SQL Editor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export all databases, use this:

```
set path=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin/
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > exported_dbs.sql
```

It worked for me in windows.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` has one important drawback, it is performance. On Windows, you can use [new shel](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysqlsh.html) for mysql - `mysqlsh`. By default, it is not installed with MySQL. You can download it from the MySQL [website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install-windows-quick.html) (windows).

`mysqlsh` can export databases in multiple threads, which can significantly improve export speed for large databases.

To export all databases please use the following command:

```
mysqlsh --mysql -u user -p -h localhost -P 3306 -- util dump-instance /tmp/sample-backup-instane
```

[More examples](https://sqlbak.com/blog/mysql-command-line-backup-top-5-cli-utilities/)